# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' in angular2.

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been building an angular2 application using this api : https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/

This api returns an array of dictionaries (sample):

```
[
{
    "id": "bitcoin",     <------ Wanna use this id
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "9347.32", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "7926060000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "158936099373", 
    "available_supply": "17003387.0", 
    "total_supply": "17003387.0", 
    "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "-0.24", 
    "percent_change_24h": "1.1", 
    "percent_change_7d": "6.62", 
    "last_updated": "1524926675"
},
```

I am using routing parameters to go to a different page like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let curr of currency" [routerLink]="['/currdetail',curr.id]">    <------ Here 
      <th scope="row">{{ curr.rank }}</th>
      <td>{{curr.name}}</td>
      <td>{{curr.symbol}}</td>
      <td>{{curr.market_cap_usd}}</td>
      <td>{{curr.price_usd}}</td>
      <td>{{curr.price_btc}} </td>
      <td>{{curr.available_supply}} </td>
      <td>{{curr['24h_volume_usd']}} </td>
      <td>{{curr.percent_change_1h}} </td>
      <td>{{curr.percent_change_24h}}</td>
      <td>{{curr.percent_change_7d}} </td>
    </tr>
```

Now i have written routes like this and included in my routing module:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'table',  component: TableComponent },
    { path: 'currdetail/:id',     component: CurrdetailComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/table', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

Currdetail component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CrypdataService } from '../crypdata.service'
import { Params, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-currdetail',
  templateUrl: './currdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./currdetail.component.css'],
  providers: [CrypdataService],
})
export class CurrdetailComponent implements OnInit {

  private curr;

  constructor(private crypdataservice: CrypdataService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  let id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.curr = this.crypdataservice.getcurr(id);
  }

  goBack(): void{
    this.location.back();
  }

}
```

Here is the crypdataservice file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CrypdataService {

  private baseUrl: string = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getcurr(id : string){
      return this.http.get(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/`+id).map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }

  getall(){
      return this.http.get(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/`).map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

It gives the following error :

```
ERROR in src/app/currdetail/currdetail.component.ts(20,44): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

I never specified id as a number, so can't figure out what is going wrong. Thanks for reading.

I want to use the api for details of the particular currency : 
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/  <---- this is the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `+` in your `id` declaration:

`let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];`

so that when you call `getcurr(id)` TypeScript doesn't think that `id` is a number

**Unary plus (+)** ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()))

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and
>   evaluates to its operand but attempts to convert it into a number, if
>   it isn't already. Although unary negation (-) also can convert
>   non-numbers, unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting
>   something into a number, because it does not perform any other
>   operations on the number. It can convert string representations of
>   integers and floats, as well as the non-string values true, false, and
>   null. Integers in both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats
>   are supported. Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If
>   it cannot parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.